# Angular 8 - Elementos en lista no se visualizan

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, mdb, md-bootstrap

estoy trabajando con las tablas de MDBoostrap, este componente lo hago funcionar con lo que el mismo tutorial indica, sin embargo debo modificar mi tabla para que despliegue los elementos que necesito.

[MDBoostrap Tabla en uso](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/tables/pagination/)

Mi header usado en la tabla seria algo como:

```
headElements = ["ClientID", "SocketID", "IP", "ACTIONS"];
```

Donde, ClientID, SocketID e IP son string. Actions son botones de acciones para cada ítem de la tabla.

Problema?
MDBoostrap me pide agregar items al `this.elements` sin embargo yo desde mi servicio estoy recibiendo una lista de objectos.

Si los agrego de esta forma:

```
this.SocketService.getClients().subscribe(data => {
  this.elements.push(...data);
});
```

La consola me devuelve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema es que, al ser un arreglo de objectos, yo debo hacer un ForEach o un `for` recorriéndole con su índice, esto me hace un problema, un loop infinito.

```
for (let i = 0; i <= this.elements.length; i++) {
    console.log(this.elements[i]);
  }
```

Pero consola me devuelve:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se supone que debo hacer un arreglo donde desencadene la lista de objectos según me pide MDBoostrap, es decir, debo tener algo similar a:

```
      this.elements.push({ClientID: STRING, SocketID: STRING2, IP: STRING3});
```

Entonces, hice otras pruebas:

Cree una variable `clients: any = [];`
Rellene clientes con el array de objetos del servicio e hice:

```
for (let i = 0; i <= this.clients.length; i++) {
    this.elements.push({
      ClientID: this.clients[0].SocketID,
      SocketID: this.clients[0].ClientID,
      IP: this.clients[0].IP
    });
  }
```

Este código da error 'undefined clients[i]'

```
for (let i = 0; i <= this.clients.length; i++) {
        this.elements.push({
          ClientID: this.clients[i].SocketID,
          SocketID: this.clients[i].ClientID,
          IP: this.clients[i].IP
        });
      }
```

Por alguna razón que desconozco, este código funciona, me devuelve el array y lo descompone en objetos... Pero, este aún no rellena la tabla.

De antemano, muchas gracias.

Nota: Los headers se muestran y en .html esta con `*ngFor="let head of headElements; let i = index"`

Answer (score 0):

tras pruebas y error, logré por mi cuenta hacer funcionar todo correctamente.
Solución? Ejecute todo el código en el subscribe.

```
ngOnInit() {
this.SocketService.getClients().subscribe(data => {
  data.forEach(element => {
    this.clients.push(element);
  });

  this.clients.forEach((element, i) => {
    this.elements.push({
      clientid: element.ClientID,
      socketid: element.SocketID,
      ipaddress: element.ClientIP
    });

    this.mdbTable.setDataSource(this.elements);
    this.elements = this.mdbTable.getDataSource();
    this.previous = this.mdbTable.getDataSource();
  });
});
}
```

Nota, puede que haya realizado un Foreach sobrante, pues es el primero. Aunque no lo he probado sin él.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]